# fail to receive multicast packet in guest os

Tags: virtualbox, multicast

Socket client [run in linux guest os] can't receive multicast packets, while tcpdump do capture
those packets.
Everything is well if run client in host os no matter the server run on linux guest or win7 host

[The Multicast Demo In C I Used](http://www.nmsl.cs.ucsb.edu/MulticastSocketsBook/#cexamples)

**Context**
Host OS: windows 7
Guest OS: centos 6.2
Virtualization: virtualbox 4.1.8

Answer (score 1):

multicast works after

1. stop iptables
2. stop selinux